# Confusion understanding Google Trends with pytrends: column normalization, search representation, and monthly aggregation

Tags: python, google-trends

The following code

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrends = TrendReq(hl='it', tz=0, timeout=None)

keywords = ['dichiarazione', 'redditi']

pytrends.build_payload(keywords, timeframe='2004-01-01 2017-01-01', geo='IT')

pytrends.interest_by_region(resolution='COUNTRY', inc_low_vol=True, inc_geo_code=False)
```

returns

[image]

I don't have a clear understanding of the results I'm obtaining. Firstly, should the column numbers not be normalized between 0 and 100, as is usually done for Google Trends? What do they represent? Why, for example, does the last column have much lower numbers than the one next to it? I wanted to focus on searches containing both the words 'dichiarazione' and 'redditi' in Italian, but I'm starting to doubt whether this code actually returns results for searches containing each of the words 'dichiarazione' and 'redditi' separately (i.e., in the second column, searches containing the single word 'dichiarazione,' and in the third column, searches containing the single word 'redditi'). Is that really the case? Additionally, I would like to obtain monthly results of searches within the specified time frame (so I would like to see this dataframe repeated for each month of the time frame), but I don't know where to start. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that achieves what you want if I understood your request correctly.

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Set up pytrends
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)

# Set keywords and location
keywords = ['dichiarazione', 'redditi']
geo_location = 'IT'

# Get timeframe (last 5 years)
end_date = datetime.datetime.now()
start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(days=5 * 365)

# Convert dates to string format
start_date_str = start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end_date_str = end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Build the payload
pytrends.build_payload(keywords, cat=0, timeframe=f'{start_date_str} {end_date_str}', geo=geo_location, gprop='')

# Get interest over time
interest_over_time_df = pytrends.interest_over_time()

# Resample the data to get monthly values
monthly_interest_df = interest_over_time_df.resample('M').sum()

# Display the results
print(monthly_interest_df)

# Plot the data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
monthly_interest_df.plot()
plt.show()
```

Here are the results:

```
~/Projects/Trends ❯ python3 trends.py                                                                     20s 09:23:36
            dichiarazione  redditi  isPartial
date
2018-11-30             40       12          0
2018-12-31            169       43          0
2019-01-31            178       48          0
2019-02-28            170       44          0
2019-03-31            237       82          0
...                   ...      ...        ...
2023-07-31            268      132          0
2023-08-31            110       53          0
2023-09-30            203       79          0
2023-10-31            226       80          0
2023-11-30             94       38          1

[61 rows x 3 columns]
```

And here is the graph:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your code is really helpful. Quick question: What does the 'isPartial' column do? Also, could you explain the numbers in the 'dichiarazione' and 'redditi' columns? Thanks again!

Comment: 'isPartial' indicates whether the data for that period is complete or partial.

Data for the most recent time periods might not be complete because it hasn't finished yet. For such periods, the 'isPartial' column is set to True.

Numbers in columns represent the relative search interest for the keywords over time. They are usually normalized by Google Trends, i.e. not absolute search counts, but resampling by month simply summed up numbers by month. I'd go dig the docs.

If you found this answer helpful, would you be willing to accept it?